# How to catch text from html page

Tags: php

I'd like to catch the word "Bronze" from this html page portion:

```
<tr  class="">
   <td align="left"  csk="Nikpai,Rohullah"><a href="/olympics/athletes/ni/rohullah-nikpai-1.html">Rohullah Nikpai</a></td>
   <td align="right" >25</td>
   <td align="left" ><a href="/olympics/summer/2012/TKW/mens-featherweight.html">Men's Featherweight</a></td>
   <td align="right"  csk="3">3T </td>
   <td align="left"  class=" Bronze" csk="1"><strong>Bronze</strong></td>
</tr>
```

I tried different code but I failed in my intent. One of many attempts is the following:

```
foreach($html4->find('td align="left" strong') as $tag4) {


                                 echo $prova =  $tag4->innertext . "\n";

                            }
```

where html4 is the entire html page I have to process.

Comment: what class is `$html4` an instanceof ?

Answer (score 0):

With following Code you can get the classname "Bronze"

```
<?php 
$html='<tr  class="">
   <td align="left"  csk="Nikpai,Rohullah"><a href="/olympics/athletes/ni/rohullah-nikpai-1.html">Rohullah Nikpai</a></td>
   <td align="right" >25</td>
   <td align="left" ><a href="/olympics/summer/2012/TKW/mens-featherweight.html">Mens Featherweight</a></td>
   <td align="right"  csk="3">3T </td>
   <td align="left"  class=" Bronze" csk="1"><strong>Bronze</strong></td>
</tr>';


$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $link) {
        echo trim($link->getAttribute('class'),' ');            
}
?>
```

Or, if you prefer the Node Value and not the class name and the csk attribut is always 1:

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $link) {
    if ($link->getAttribute('csk')=="1"){
        echo $link->nodeValue;
    }
}
```